# new to coding please help Printing a string

Tags: python, string

user_word and user_number are read from input. Output user_word, followed by ',' (a comma) and user_number using a single statement.  Ex: If the input is: Amy 5 then the output is: Amy,5

```
user_word = input()
user_number = int(input())

print(user_word +",",user_number)
```

error is
Output is nearly correct, but whitespace differs. See highlights below.
Special character legend
Your output
Amy, 5
Expected output
Amy,5

Output is nearly correct, but whitespace differs. See highlights below.
Special character legend
Your output
Amy, 5
Expected output
Amy,5

im getting a space between and when i try to concatenate is says i get another error

1st week 0 experience please help

Comment: try `print(user_word +","+user_number)` instead

Comment: This is because the default "sep" of print is ' ',

Answer (score 0):

Try f strings:

```
print(f"{user_word},{user_number}")
```

Answer (score 0):

By default print() function has a separator " ".
That means print('abcd', 'xyz') will actually print 'abcd xyz'.
Here we can manually set the separator by mentioning the 'sep' parameter in print() function.

For examples,

INPUT : print('abcd', 'xyz', sep='-')
OUTPUT: abcd-xyz

INPUT : print('abcd', 'pqrs', 'xyz', sep=',')
OUTPUT: abcd-pqrs-xyz

INPUT : print('abcd', 'xyz, sep='*')
OUTPUT: abcd,xyz

INPUT : print('abcd', 'xyz', sep='')
OUTPUT: abcdxyz

INPUT : print('abcd', 'pqrs', 'xyz', sep='')
OUTPUT: abcdpqrsxyz

In your case you should write print(user_word +",",user_number, sep='')

Comment: Your output is sometimes incorrect.